# How to import multiple csv files and concatenate into one DataFrame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have problem `No objects to concatenate`. I can not import .csv files from main and its subdirectories to concatenate them into one DataFrame. I am using pandas. Old answers did not help me so please do not mark as duplicated.

Folder structure is like that

```
main/*.csv
main/name1/name1/*.csv
main/name1/name2/*.csv
main/name2/name1/*.csv
main/name3/*.csv
```

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

folder_selected = 'C:/Users/jacob/Documents/csv_files'
```

1. not works

```
frame = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder_selected, "/*.csv"))))
```

2. not works

```
csv_paths = glob.glob('*.csv')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(folder_selected) for folder_selected in csv_paths]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

3. not works

```
            all_files = []
            
            all_files = glob.glob (folder_selected + "/*.csv")
            
            file_path = []
            for file in all_files:
                df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, header=0)
                file_path.append(df)
                    
        frame = pd.concat(file_path, axis=0, ignore_index=False)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to search the subdirectories recursively.

```py
folder = 'C:/Users/jacob/Documents/csv_files'
path = folder+"/**/*.csv"
```

1. Using `glob.iglob`

```py
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.iglob(path, recursive=True)))
```

2. Using `glob.glob`

```py
csv_paths = glob.glob(path, recursive=True)
dfs = [pd.read_csv(csv_path) for csv_path in csv_paths]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

3. Using `os.walk`

```py
file_paths = []
for base, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.csv'):
        file_paths.append(os.path.join(base, file))
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in file_paths])
```

4. Using `pathlib`

```py
from pathlib import Path
files = Path(folder).rglob('*.csv')
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, files))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my day. I chose third method and now it is working like a charm.

Comment: Happy to help :) @AlexRodrigues. If it helped you can you upvote the answer?

Comment: Yes, sorry I just forgot. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Check Dask Library as following, which reads many files to one df

```
>>> import dask.dataframe as dd
>>> df = dd.read_csv('data*.csv')
```

Read their docs
https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html#Read-CSV-files

Comment: This is a good answer. However, all of the files would need to be in the same directory. Also, I would add that to transform to a pandas dataframe, you would need to add `.compute()` to the end, e.g. `df = dd.read_csv('data*.csv').compute()`

Answer (score 2):

Python’s `pathlib` is a tool for such tasks

```py
from pathlib import Path

FOLDER_SELECTED = 'C:/Users/jacob/Documents/csv_files'

path = Path(FOLDER_SELECTED) / Path("main")

# grab all csvs in main and subfolders
df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f.name) for f in path.rglob("*.csv"))
```

## Note:

If the CSV need preprocing, you can create a read_csv function to deal with issues and place it in place of pd.read_csv